# Check location in background using cordova

Tags: cordova, geolocation

I want to check user location in background.
For example, everyday at 9am.
Is it possible to schedule it in cordova?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use services in android. They run in background but can be killed by the system if they consume lots of memory. In your case it should not be killed.

More information [Android Services](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html)

Answer (score 0):

question might be old, but posting this might help others

using the following plugin you can fetch locations even if the application is in the background.
it has options like *'stopOnTerminate'* and *'startonboot'*, which helps you getting you location updates even after the reboot or OS kills the app.

you can also try *interval* option of a plugin for your purpose.

https://github.com/mauron85/cordova-plugin-background-geolocation